# Check the statistics/success transmissions of ping command

Tags: linux

I am new to shell scripting, hence have very less knowledge on linux commands. I am pinging a host for exactly 10 times. I would like to know, how to get the no. of packets successfully transmitted. E.g

```
    ping -c 10 12.1.4.1
    PING 12.1.4.1 (12.1.4.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 12.1.4.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=439 ms
    64 bytes from 12.1.4.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=577 ms
    64 bytes from 12.1.4.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=435 ms
    64 bytes from 12.1.4.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=483 ms
    64 bytes from 12.1.4.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=519 ms
    64 bytes from 12.1.4.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=487 ms
    64 bytes from 12.1.4.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=128 time=470 ms
    64 bytes from 12.1.4.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=128 time=516 ms
    64 bytes from 12.1.4.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=128 time=467 ms
    64 bytes from 12.1.4.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=128 time=544 ms

    --- 12.1.4.1 ping statistics ---
    10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9013ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 435.527/494.221/577.189/42.922 ms
```

The output should be 10.

I can redirect the output to a file and then use cut/sed command to get the value "10" packets received, but I want to do in one line after the ping command.

Answer (score 0):

We just need to select the fourth column of the line that contains the word "packets":

```
ping -c 10 12.1.4.1 | egrep packets | cut -d" " -f4
```

Comment: No, that number will aways be 10. Perhaps `awk '/packets transmitted/ { print $4 }'` instead, which is also more robust against spacing variations.

Comment: You're right, @tripleee. I have updated the answer. Thanks!